# responsive multi row div

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to make a multi row div? Just a 2 basic rows .

I have been able to make a static example of what I am looking for. However I'm not too sure how I would make this responsive. Using percents % with current css doesn't work.

#### HTML

```
<div class='wrap'>
<div class = "blocks">
    div 1
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 2
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 3
</div>

<div class = "blocks">
    div 4
</div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.blocks {display: inline-block; border: solid 1px red; width: 100px;}

.wrap{
    width:210px;   
    border: solid 1px black;
}
```

Comment: percentages are perfectly working : https://jsfiddle.net/qyj73bec/

Comment: No you lost a row. There were two rows. With responsive there is only 1 row now. I need two rows as in my example.

Comment: oh ok. I didn't understand that... Then you can just make `[100/<number_of_divs>*2]%` if this is dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```css
.blocks {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    border: solid 1px red;
    width: 25%;
    box-sizing : border-box
}

.wrap {
    width:400px;   
    padding: 1px;
    border: solid 1px black;
}

.wrap:before,
.wrap:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.wrap:after {
    clear: both;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .blocks {
        width:50%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .blocks {
        width:100%;
    }

    .wrap {
        width:100%;   
    }
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
    <div class = "blocks">
        div 1
    </div>

    <div class = "blocks">
        div 2
    </div>

    <div class = "blocks">
        div 3
    </div>

    <div class = "blocks">
        div 4
    </div>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xd45kame/))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use percentage values for your block widths, you have to make sure that there is no blank between the blocks (1) and that the borders and paddings of your blocks are included in the percentage (2).

```
.blocks {
    width: 50%;
    float: left; /* (1) */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* (2) */
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

For adding margin between two blocks, you have to give the margin in `%` and make sure that two blocks width and the margin add up to 100%. I created an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkp3dmsx/).

Comment: That works. If I had two media queries, could go from one row to two rows?

Comment: Sure you can. If you go with the mobile first approach for example, then you give every block a 100% width and if the width of the page is higher than some value you can say that a block has a width of 50%. I updated the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkp3dmsx/1/).

Comment: I'm not trying to pick hairs but that went from two rows to 4 rows. I needed one row to 2 rows at different media queries. SORRY for the confusion. I see what you did however. Maybe I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid. The grid will help you create multiple columns on a row.

However if you want use custom css then:

```
.wrap{
width:100%;
clear:both;  
border: solid 1px black;
}
.blocks {
width:25%;border: 1px solid red;
}
```